# How do I speed up iterative calculations in python?

Tags: python

I am using python to iterate through a large number of calculations. This example has 177147 calculations, and it has been executing "results.append" for 10 minutes without completion.  I expected that this would run in a matter of seconds. Is there a faster way to accomplish this? I would like to be able to run ~100,000,000 calculations in my real-world problem.

```
import itertools

a=[1]
b=[1]
c=[1,2,3]
d=[1,2,3]
e=[1,2,3]
f=[1,2,3]
g=[1,2,3]
h=[1,2,3]
i=[1,2,3]
j=[1,2,3]
k=[1,2,3]
l=[1,2,3]
m=[1,2,3]

params=list(itertools.product(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m))

def TestFunction(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m):
    output=a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m
    return output

results=[]
[results.append(TestFunction(*list(params)[x]))for x in range(len(params))]
```

Comment: Why not using generator? What that calculations are for?

Comment: You're generating all permutations up front in `params` which isn't particularly efficient... then, for your results, you're building up a list of `None` as `.append` doesn't return anything, and inside that - you're creating a copy of your `params` list - taking a certain index, then discarding that copy again and again and again...

Comment: Are you basically after - `results = [sum(args) for args in itertools.product(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m)]`?

Comment: No, the actual calculation is more complicated than the sum.  The end goal is to make two sets of different calculations (values and probabilities), sort the pairs of results in descending order by value, find the cumulative sum of the value, and plot the result.

Comment: Also, at 100M, perhaps it is time to use numpy.

Answer (score 4):

As Jon said in the comments, your code is creating a *lot* of unnecessary lists, which not only wastes RAM, it takes time. Here's an optimised version of your code that executes in around half a second on my old 2GHz 32 bit machine.

```
from itertools import product

data = (
    [1],
    [1],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3],
)

def TestFunction(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m):
    return a + b + c + d + e + f + g + h + i + j + k + l + m

results = [TestFunction(*params) for params in product(*data)]
print(len(results))
```

**output**

```
177147
```

Comment: and rather use `list(map(sum, product(*data)))` for 1.5x further speed-up

Comment: @AnttiHaapala `TestFunction` is just a dummy function that does _something_ with the passed args, the real program performs a more complicated calculation, as the OP [explained earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40715685/how-do-i-speed-up-iterative-calculations-in-python/40716177?noredirect=1#comment68659028_40715685). So I left that function in its original state (apart from adding some whitespace).

Comment: then, itertools.starmap

Answer (score -4):

You won't like the answer, but a good way of doing it is Cython. You're probably going to have to make your own module, do it in C, and then put it into python. I've never been able to do it, but that's the simplest way I can think of for speeding it up.